# cannot read from USB Stick

Tags: bootloader

Installing on Lenovo Z580, during boot up process the bios menu shows that the USB Stick is detected but on selecting it it opens Windows 8 which is originally my operating system. i have tried Universal Usb installer and poweriso but nothing works. Anyone with past experience please help me out.
Thank You!

Comment: One possibility: You have created a (Legacy or  UEFI)  liveUSB which is disabled in your BIOS : Go to Boot List Option-> select UEFI or Legacy (according to your liveUSB) and save and try.....   Please attach a photo of your BIOS->BOOT

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable hibernation and fast startup in Windows.
Otherwise your computer will always boot into Windows.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings.
When fast startup is enabled, disable (uncheck) it.
Shutdown the PC completely - do NOT reboot.
Now you should be able to boot from USB.